# Find where Certbot creates .well-known/acme-challenge folder

Tags: ubuntu, certbot

I need to change my Nginx config to allow access to the `.well-known/acme-challenge`. However I can't target that folder, because I don't know where it is located.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382739/certbot-not-creating-acme-challenge-folder) indicates that I have to change the root to `/var/www/domain/`, however that folder doesn't exist on my VPS.

So how can I find where Certbot creates the `.well-known/acme-challenge` instead?